# Why do my variables keep being kicked out of a similarity search if they have the same field name?

Tags: arcgis, similarity-search

I've been trying to conduct a similarity search for my arcgis project on measles risk in England, but I keep being told that there are no valid fields left in my similarity search, even though I've been careful to make sure they're the same name and all the values are present and sufficiently different.

I've been trying to conduct a similarity search on arcgis pro using a worst-case polygon (which I made using the Copy Features geoprocessing tool) and then replacing all the values in the worst-case polygon with data I have connected to my England layer. This data was imported as a CSV and linked to the England polygon layer using an add join.

The field names for the variables were different in the England attribute table and the worst-case attribute table, so I used add field and calculate field to create duplicates that shared names across both layers. I haven't deleted the differently named variables and there are a few variables which are retained that are just geography variables (lat, long, shape length/area).

I've also checked the data use the same mapping/coordinates system (they do) and I've run through the data table to check for null values (there aren't any). However, I still keep getting this error message: [ERROR 001585](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01576-01600-001585.htm): Missing/Invalid Attribute(s). No valid fields are left in the list of attributes to consider.

But when I look at this online I can't see anything I'm missing- so I'm none the wiser on why the smilarity search can't be conducted.
Any help would be most appreciated!
All the best,
From Daniel